# Creating database that includes Postgis functionalities

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3. I wanted to create a database that supports Postgis functionalities.

In creating database,under the template,there is no option called "template_Postgis".

According to my knowledge that should be selected in order to save shape file in to the data base.

Can any one of you help me to solve this? Should I change my version?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you shouldn't be using 9.3 anymore. It will be out of support in the next months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `CREATE EXTENSION` to install PostGIS.

Of course you can create a template database that has PostGIS installed and use this to get databases that are already prepared, but you'll have to create that template database yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "template postgis". [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) is an [extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-extensions.html) to Postgres that needs to be [installed](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db_extensions), once you have created your database using the [`create extension`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) command:

So you need to download and copy the PostGIS files to the Postgres `share` directory. How exactly you need to do that depends on your operating system.

Once that is done, connect to the database where you want to enable PostGIS (as the superuser), then run

```
create extension postgis;
```